# Database Error: Unable to connect to the database:The MySQL adapter "mysql" is not available

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I'm receiving this error message :

**Database Error: Unable to connect to the database:The MySQL adapter "mysql" is not available**

while connecting to a website. I'm using php,apache and mysql. My server runs in Red Hat 5.4

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: That's nice. Do you have a question?

Comment: seem that the mysql driver is missing

Comment: post a question which is worth answering

Comment: @Rajesh - WAMP on RedHat: interesting idea.

Comment: @rajesh No, I'm using apache.

Comment: @DICK use `yum install php-mysql` in the command line.

Comment: @RabNawaz i was able to logged in using putty.

Comment: @Mihai Stancu: I think WAMP could be run on RedHat. Refer [link](http://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/adina/teaching/it350/fall2012/labs/InstallWAMP_Perl.htm)

Comment: @rajesh: **WAMP = Windows, Apache, MySQL and PHP.** LAMP = Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP. **XAMPP = Cross-platform Apache, MySQL, PHP and Perl.**

Answer (score 2):

Run

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

Search for 'mysql'. see if it is installed. If not reinstall your package.

Comment: Only sqlite, I didn't install the package. I installed apache,php and mysql individually.

Answer (score 2):

Install **php-mysql** from the command line (putty).

```
yum install php-mysql
```

As it is apparent that you have installed `apache`, `mysql` and `php` manually from source not from the repository, using the above command may not yield the correct results.

The yum repository may have a different version of `php-mysql` than the one required by the `mysql`, `php` versions you have manually installed.

In this case you should look for the `php-mysql` source and manually install it to (but be careful about finding the correct version).

This should help installing very recent versions of apache/mysql/php from repositories (including that driver): http://www.tecmint.com/install-apache-mysql-php-on-redhat-centos-fedora/

Comment: But I already installed it.

Comment: You probably installed **php** and **mysql** not **php-mysql**.

Comment: Is it different? I installed php,mysql and apache individually and not as package

Comment: **php-mysql** is a communication package between **php** and **mysql**. It adds the **mysql** driver to **php**.

Comment: I see. But no package available for that php-mysql. I'll be trying to look for an installer.

Comment: Is that the result for `yum install php-mysql`? or were you looking for the source files?

Comment: Yes, that's the result for trying yum install php-mysql

Comment: That package should be available in the repositories. Try updating the repository list..

Comment: The php-mysql has been installed but to no avail.